# Dynamically updating DOMs with divs using jquery using loop

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I have a jsp which will show the data dynamically in different div. This is my jsp code

```
<div class="userProfileDetails">
            <div id="ignorecrossbefore_1" style="display: none">
                <div class="posrelative">
                    <img width="150" height="150" border="0"
                        src="https://content.screencast.com/users/RaviKumar87/folders/Jing/media/fd8c7ca4-1d71-483c-8b3a-8fa67e537c23/2019-06-19_1908.png">
                </div>
                <div class="fleft mediumtxt"
                    style="width: 900px; margin-left: 177px; margin-top: -142px;">
                    <div class="location-icon clr5 padb10" alt="Location"
                        title="Location">
                        <h4>
                            <span class="input-data" id="searchProfileName"></span>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span class="input-field">City </span> 
                                <span class="input-data" id="cityName"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="input-field">Age </span> 
                                <span class="input-data" id="age"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="input-field">Height </span> 
                                <span class="input-data" id="heigth"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="input-field">Caste </span> 
                                <span class="input-data" id="caste"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="input-field">Education </span> 
                                <span class="input-data" id="eudcation"></span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="input-field">Occupation </span> 
                                <span class="input-data" id="occupation"></span>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm search-btn-padding"
                        style="color: white;" onclick="searchProfile()">View Profile</a>

                </div>
            </div>






        </div>
```

This is my jquery code

```
success: function(result){
            $('#ignorecrossbefore_1').show();
             $(result).each(function(i,element){
                    $('#searchProfileName').html(element.userBirthName);
                    $('#cityName').html(element.presetnAddressCity);
                    $('#age').html(element.userAge);
                    $('#heigth').html(element.userheight);
                    $('#caste').html(element.userCasteName);
                    $('#eudcation').html(element.highestEducation);
                    $('#occupation').html(element.employedIn);                       
                });

        },
```

How do I dynamically update the span with different data, so, it can look like in different div like below link:

https://content.screencast.com/users/RaviKumar87/folders/Jing/media/79b241c6-776d-4d1a-9e61-e74a880b9aff/2019-06-19_1912.png

Comment: You need a couple of things: First, you need to find the way to render several times your "ignorecrossbefore_1". You might find this easier if you did on your JSP. Second, you have to identify your elements with some kind of number or code to make them unique (for example "#cityName0", "#cityName1", etc. Otherwise your jQuery would not find the exact element you want to replace with the values of your success callback function. When you have your elements numbered you could do something like $("#cityName" + i).html(...);

Comment: For each result, you could create a new element (DOM), containing your `element` data, and then attach it to `#ignorecrossbefore_1` or the element you require to contain your info...

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a new element for each result:

```
success: function(result){
    let elem;
    let cntid = 0;
     $(result).each(function(i,element){
            elem = $('<div><span id="searchProfileName"' + cntid + '>' + element.userBirthName + '</span><span id="cityName"' + cntid + '>' + element.presetnAddressCity + '</span><span id="age"' + cntid + '>' + element.userAge + '</span><span id="heigth"' + cntid + '>' + element.userheight +'</span><span id="caste"' + cntid + '>' + element.userCasteName + '</span><span id="eudcation"' + cntid + '>' + element.highestEducation + '</span><span id="occupation"' + cntid +'>' + element.employedIn + '</span></div>');                                    $('#ignorecrossbefore_1').append(elem);
            cntid++;
        });
},
```

The idea is to insert a new DOM element for each of the results fetched...
The new lines are not necessary, they are there just to make the code more readable.

Comment: Hi @diego, I am very new to jquery and when I am using your code, it is giving an error on id, please let me know how do I correct it?

Comment: @Ravi, please share the error you are getting so I can help

Comment: I review the code and there were some errors on it... I corrected them... you can try it again...

Comment: Carrascas, I am not getting any error with this code but it is not displaying any output on the UI. Please help me. Let me know if I can contact you through any mode of communication?

Comment: And how to I update the image also, Please help me in showing the output on the UI. It is not displaying anything on the UI

Comment: I was missing a quotation, I updated the code and now it should be fine

Comment: Hi @Diego, image is not showing on the UI and if you see my jsp code, by default I am showing the image with style:none, how do I show the image with this jquery.... Let me know if I should share you entire code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195204/discussion-between-ravi-and-diego-carrascal).

Comment: Hi @Diego, everything is working fine now after a small changes. Please suggest, how do change the image dynamically like with changed birthname, cityname etc.

Comment: Do the img source comes also in the fetched `result`? if so, just add the img element like so: `'<img id="profileIMG' + cntid + '" width="150" height="150" border="0" src="' + element.YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME + '">'`